# How to create, read and write XML C# windows forms?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I want to create an XML file through c# and need to read and write on it.

The data I need to store are just strings and integers.

Comment: Ever tried already posted questions about XML? Or google?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly three options (I shall assume at least .NET 3.5):

1. Settings as per @Andrew
2. The built in Serialization tools which work a treat and do some of the heavy lifting for you.
3. Use Linq to XML (XDocument, XElement, XAttribute etc) which makes it relatively trivial to manually read and write XML in whatever format you require .

To be honest you'll probably achieve the result you want fastest using Linq to XML and its also probably the most flexible approach however you ought to consider what is the most appropriate solution for your particular application - e.g. if the values you're saving *are* application settings then using the configuration/settings may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Using Settings in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28VS.80%29.aspx):

> The .NET Framework 2.0 allows you to
>   create and access values that are
>   persisted between application
>   execution sessions. These values are
>   called settings. Settings can
>   represent user preferences, or
>   valuable information the application
>   needs to use. For example, you might
>   create a series of settings that store
>   user preferences for the color scheme
>   of an application. Or you might store
>   the connection string that specifies a
>   database that your application uses.
>   Settings allow you to both persist
>   information that is critical to the
>   application outside of the code, and
>   to create profiles that store the
>   preferences of individual users.

Answer (score 1):

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Data;

    namespace DomenNotification
    {
        class CreateXML
        {
            public static string Title = "";
            public static string Hosting = "";
            public static string Startdate = "";
            public static string ExpDate = "";
            public static string Username = "";
            public static string Password = "";

            public string Title1 { get; set; }
            public string Hosting1 { get; set; }
            public string Startdate1 { get; set; }
            public string ExpDate1 { get; set; }
            public string Username1 { get; set; }
            public string Password1 { get; set; }


            public string filePath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + "\\Notification.xml"; // This is the path of MyDocuments folder of your pc

           //---------------create xml file -----------------------

            public bool isXmlExist(string filePath)
            {
                bool result = false;
                try
                {
                    if (File.Exists(filePath))// Checking the file if exist
                    {
                        Startdate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                        result = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                        XmlElement element1 = doc.CreateElement("", "XML", "");
                        doc.AppendChild(element1);

                        //--------------creating the node elements

                        XmlElement element2 = doc.CreateElement("", "Title", "");
                        element1.AppendChild(element2);

                        XmlElement element3 = doc.CreateElement("", "Hosting", "");
                        element1.AppendChild(element3);

                        XmlElement element4 = doc.CreateElement("", "StartDate", "");
                        element1.AppendChild(element4);

                        XmlElement element5 = doc.CreateElement("", "ExpDate", "");
                        element1.AppendChild(element5);

                        XmlElement element6 = doc.CreateElement("", "Username", "");
                        element1.AppendChild(element6);

                        XmlElement element7 = doc.CreateElement("", "password", "");
                        element1.AppendChild(element7);

                        doc.Save(filePath);
                        Startdate = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                        //writeXml(filePath);

                        result = true;
                    }
                }
                catch { result = false; }
                return result;
            }

                //-------------------Getting the xml data from creating file ---                 
            public DataSet getXmlData(string filePath)
            {
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                try
                {
                    if (isXmlExist(filePath))
                    {
                        ds.Clear();
                        ds.ReadXml(filePath);
                        int table = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables.Count);
                        for (int i = 0; i <= table; i++)
                        {
                            Title = ds.Tables[i].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                            Hosting = ds.Tables[i].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                            Startdate = ds.Tables[i].Rows[0][2].ToString();
                            ExpDate = ds.Tables[i].Rows[0][3].ToString();
                            Username = ds.Tables[i].Rows[0][4].ToString();
                            Password = ds.Tables[i].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                        }
                        return ds;
                    }
                    return ds;
                }
                catch { return ds; }
            }

//------------------- insert the data into created xml file--------------

            public bool writeXml(string filePath,string title,string hosting,string sdate,string exdate,string username,string password)
            {
                bool result = false;
                Title = title;
                Hosting = hosting;
                Startdate = sdate;
                ExpDate = exdate;
                Username = username;
                Password = password;
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                ds.Clear();
                ds.ReadXml(path);
                int i = 0;
                i = Convert.ToInt32(ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count) - 1;
                try
                {

                    dt.Columns.Add("Title");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Hosting");
                    dt.Columns.Add("StartDate");
                    dt.Columns.Add("ExpDate");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Username");
                    dt.Columns.Add("Password");


                    dt.Rows.Add(dt.NewRow());
                    dt.Rows[i]["Title"] = Title;
                    dt.Rows[i]["Hosting"] = Hosting;
                    dt.Rows[i]["Startdate"] = Startdate;
                    dt.Rows[i]["ExpDate"] = ExpDate;
                    dt.Rows[i]["Username"] = Username;
                    dt.Rows[i]["Password"] = Password;

                    ds.Tables.Add(dt);

                    ds.WriteXml(path);
                    result = true;
                }
                catch { }
                return result;
            }

        }
    }
```